# How can I remove spaces between span tags, while remain spaces in each span tag?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

My problem is that: Between spans, there unexpected spaces are appeared.

So I tried to remove them with setting `font-size: 0` into the wrapper `<div>` tag. Then it removes not only spaces between `<span>` tags, but also spaces in each `<span>` tag.

```css
.word-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
.letter-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.tried-with-font {
  font-size: 0;
}
.tried-with-font span {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="word-space">
  <span>My name </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>Antonio.</span>
</div>

<div class="letter-space">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>

<h3>The result I tried:</h3>

<div class="tried-with-font">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>
```

Question: How can I remove spaces between span tags, while remain spaces in each span tag?

> In fact, the values which are in span tags are dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried using `nbsp;` for the space you need in the span?

Comment: @callback Actually, the values of spans are dynamic. I am using vuejs. That means there can be a lot of conditions like such example.

Comment: How much control of the HTML do you have? Do you need it formatted in that way, or does it get auto-formatted?

Comment: @justrhysism Yes I need to format them with in css. The values are *dynamic*.

Comment: _“but also spaces in each <span> tag.”_ - no, that is not what is going on here. The space you had between `ch` and `Results` was **not** due to the leading space character you put into `<span> Results.</span>` - such leading and trailing whitespace around the text content gets removed automatically, according to HTML rules. You had a space between those two words, because you had whitespace between the two span elements. You removed _that_ by setting the font-size of the parent to 0.

Answer (score 2):

### Why it's doing what it's doing:

By default, browsers collapse all white space (including new lines) into a single "space" character. This is described in the MDN CSS docs on [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values):

> **`white-space: normal;`**
>      Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as necessary to fill line boxes.

I think it would be worth reading this article about white-space in HTML "[When does white space matter in HTML?](https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33)" which explains this in great detail.

### Solution:

You can tell the browser to render the white-space within your `<span>` by setting:

```css
.my-span {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

#### Also:

I'm not sure if with this you still need to *remove* the white-space in between spans, but I think it's worth considering the `float` property rather than fiddling with `font-size`.

```css
.with-float span {
  float: left;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-float">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

YO !! Your code is perfectly right. It actually works fine, the only reason its not working proper in this specific scenario.

```
<span>ch</span>
<span> Results.</span>
```

The white space at the beginning and end of the tag are trimmed off by browser. As you can see in below example.

**Solution** : Just replace first/last or all spaces with `$nbsp` and it should work properly as you wish with your css :)

In your case, since the space is in beginning, it would be.

```
<span>ch</span>
<span>&nbsp Results.</span>
```

Check below example for both the issue and solution parts implemented :)

```css
.word-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
.letter-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.tried-with-font {
  font-size: 0;
}
.tried-with-font span {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="word-space">
  <span>My name </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>Antonio.</span>
</div>

<div class="letter-space">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>

<h3>The result I tried:</h3>

<div class="tried-with-font">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
  <span>&nbsp Results2. Text with middle space</span>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But the values in span tags are dynamic and they can be updated by script.

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is acceptable to you, then you can do it by gathering all textnodes that are "whitespace-only or empty" and removing them from the DOM, as follows:

```js
function getEmptyNodesUnder(node){
  var result = [];
  for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      if (node.textContent.trim().length === 0)
        result.push(node);
    }
    else {
      result = result.concat(getEmptyNodesUnder(node));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// Find the <body> tag, or target e.g. a certain div
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

// Process everything in the body
var emptyNodes = getEmptyNodesUnder(body);
for (var i = 0; i < emptyNodes.length; i++)
  emptyNodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(emptyNodes[i]);
```

```html
<div>
  <span>My name </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>Antonio.</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>My name </span>
  <span>is</span>
  <span>not</span>
  <span> Henry.</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Definitely not the best solution, but you can put on container with the class "letter-space" a `display: flex` style and then replace in all your strings which you will put in the span the space with a hidden character (between the brackets) [ ‏‏‎ ]. That worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `white-space` algorithm

```css
.word-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
.letter-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.tried-with-font {
  font-size: 0;
}
.tried-with-font span {
  font-size: 18px;
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="word-space">
  <span>My name </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>Antonio.</span>
</div>

<div class="letter-space">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>

<h3>The result I tried:</h3>

<div class="tried-with-font">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>

<div class="tried-with-font">
  <span>My name </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>Antonio.</span>
</div>
```

Or consider a small hack with inline-block and pseudo element. This will work better in order to collapse contiguous spaces inside spans:

```css
.word-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
.letter-space {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.tried-with-font {
  font-size: 0;
}
.tried-with-font span {
  font-size: 18px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.tried-with-font span:before,
.tried-with-font span:after {
  content:"\200B";
}
```

```html
<div class="word-space">
  <span>My name </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>Antonio.</span>
</div>

<div class="letter-space">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span> Results.</span>
</div>

<h3>The result I tried:</h3>

<div class="tried-with-font">
  <span>Sear</span>
  <span>ch</span>
  <span>    Results.</span>
</div>

<div class="tried-with-font">
  <span>My name   </span>
  <span>is    </span>
  <span>Antonio.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: :( As you can see in your snippet, your answer is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @Antonio how it's wrong? you said *How can I remove spaces between span tags, while remain spaces in each span tag?* I kept the space inside each span while the font-size:0 removed the one between span

Comment: Please try to run your snippet. The last sentence is working weirdly. :(

Comment: @Antonio what browser are you using? it's fine for me using Chrome and FF

Comment: I am using chrome. And I tried on my project which is based on vuejs. but it is not working. Sorry to say about that. But if I tried your snippet in edit mode, it seems like it is working well. I don't know why it is.

Comment: @Antonio then the issue isn't my code since it works find standalone. Probably there is some issue or more CSS involved in your VueJS code

Comment: @Antonio don't worry about the downvote, simply try to figure out what your code is changing to mine making it not working, if you can share a link I can probably help you

Comment: @Antonio did you find the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199303/discussion-between-antonio-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score -1):

Your spans have line breaks in between. Try putting them next to each other in one line - not a single white space in between. Otherwise, the spaces would be expected behaviour for inline spans.

Answer (score -1):

I just saw your leading and trailing spaces. Remove them and all should be fine, because spaces between spans are added automatically, if there is white space between those.